# Can you upgrade an iMac?

Tags: upgrade, imac

So I'm pretty close to picking up a new computer, and I'm thinking of getting an iMac and loading it with parallels or bootcamp so i can keep running Windows 7 on it.

My only concern is being able to upgrade.

Apple doesn't give you much in the way of customization, especially with video cards.

So, can you even upgrade them? If so, is it a pretty arduous task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more RAM.  That's about it. Its possible to do hard drive swaps as well, but its a much more tedious task. If you are really concerned about upgrading, get a Mac Pro.

Oh, and I'd go with VMWare Fusion and not Parallels.

Comment: Is the video card embedded?  damn you apple!

Comment: +1: I have an iMac and the upgrade path is very limited. I'd give you another +1 for VMWare as well, if I could :-)

Comment: @Jack: The iMac is designed for users who are not as tech-savvy and are less likely to want to upgrade/tinker with their machines. The Mac Pro is more what you want, although it will carry a very different price tag.

Comment: Right - I love the form factor.  I don't like laptops, but I want some portability.  My iPad isn't cutting it for productivity, so I'm looking at an iMac.

I just don't like the fact that I'm going to spend $2000 on something, and can't really upgrade it.

Comment: @Josh - I want something more portable, so not going to get a Mac Pro.  The price is ridiculous too.

Comment: Yes, it would be awesome to have the option to pop in a PCIe expansion card, but I imagine that would make the iMac significantly bulkier and less portable. Also, the built-in display doesn't exactly come with a standard DVI connector. It's all about trade offs, you can either have an all-in-one machine, or a less streamlined box that you can upgrade using standard parts. The Mac Pro takes the latter approach, but the Mac Pro is not up to date with the latest and greatest tech.